# Use static launch Images instead of launch file

Tags: ios

I want to use static launch Images instead of launch file, so I have created a `LaunchImage` folder in `Images.xcassets`. I have also deleted `LaunchScreen.xib` and made some settings.[image][image]

But on iOS Simulator, the launch image is still the same as before without the images I have added. How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to let the field `Launch Screen File` empty. If you let this field fill, it will be used by your project.

Also, if you don't have any launch image sources in your cassettes, you will just have a black screen until you fill them.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to add images of the correct sizes (for all device sizes that your app supports).